# Why does ReactJS npm take so long to install on my machine

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a machine, but I have problems every time I need to do some npm stuff, but I'm not sure why what's a thing I should check it out?

Comment: I don't really have a lot of modules, but the npm thing takes like a long time for some reason

Comment: internet speed test, goog it to find your speed. Update your NPM, OS then Try! It doesn't take so long when It works, about 10min, if the connection is too slow.

Comment: Thank you BloodyLogic for your answer, I think internet speed might be an issue...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should check: 
Do you have enough RAM on your computer?
What is your network speed? If it's slow that could be an issue when downloading packages from the internet. 
Do you have the latest version of npm installed?

Comment: I'm not sure what my speed is, I'll have to google it and get back to you